# Finding cell with same value as function from access log

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got this piece of code that is supposed to take the function getUserEmail() (That works perfectly) then go through every row of my Access log, and if it finds the same email take the column to the left of it, where the name is. Atm it only returns my else value, which is, if it can't find a user to the email, it just returns the email.

```js
function getUserName()  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Access List");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var userEmail = getUserEmail();
  var userName = "";

  for (var row = 1; row <= lastRow; row++){ 
    var EmailRange = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
      if(userEmail == EmailRange) {
         var userName =+ sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
         return userName;
      }
       else if (userName == ""){
         return userEmail;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing `[i]` which is an array to sheet.getRange(), try passing just `i` instead.

Comment: Noticed that and something else, however it still parses the else every time
Updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone stumbles upon this I got it working by tweaking my first code

```js
function getUserName()  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Access List");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var userEmail = getUserEmail();

  //Logger.log(userEmail);
  //Logger.log(lastRow);

  for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++) { 
      //Logger.log(sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue());
      if(userEmail == sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue()) {
         return sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();

      }
      else if(i == lastRow) {
      return userEmail;
    }
  }
}
```

Works like a charm

Comment: Please describe the changes that you made to the code on the question

Comment: I don't actually know, however it all started working after I used my i variable in the else if statement. Might be a necessary connection there for it to work. And I don't define a variable within the for loop anymore